# Last record in each group

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I use oracle 11.2, I try to get last record in each group.

In my ce table I have id, date, name field.

```
select ce1.*
from ce ce1
inner join 
  (select account_id, max(date) as max_date from ce group by account_id ) as group_id
   on ce1.account_id=group_id.account_id
  and ce1.date=group_id.max_date
where ce1.account_id in (....)
```

that work well

I try to convert it in jpql without success, my jpa implementation is hibernate

```
select ce1
    from ce ce1
    inner join 
      (select accountId as accountId, max(date) maxDate from ce group by accountId ) as group_id
       on ce1.accountId=group_id.accountId
      and ce1.date=group_id.maxDate
    where ce1.accountId in (....)
```

Jpa don't seem to like innerjoin and the max

unexpected token (
unexpected token max

Comment: can you post the entity Ce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the entity Ce:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Ce> cq = cb.createQuery(Ce.class);

Root<Ce> rootCe = cq.from(Ce.class);

Subquery<Date> sqMaxDate = cq.subquery(Date.class);
Root<Ce> sqRootCe = sqMaxDate.from(Ce.class);
sqMaxDate.where(cb.equal(rootCe.get(Ce_.accountId),sqRootCe.get(Ce_.accountId)));
sqMaxDate.select(cb.max(sqRootCe.get(Ce_.date)));

cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(rootCe.get(Ce_.date),sqMaxDate.getSelection()),
                 rootCe.get(Ce_.accountId).in([...])));
```

This query result:

```
Select * from CE ce1
Where ce1.account_id in ([...])
    and ce1.date = (
        select max(date) from CE ce2
        where ce1.account_id = ce2.account_id
    );
```

Without the entity I believe that this solution is valid. We get the maximum date for each acount id and set it as a condition of the main query